# Articles in "Result is _ map of _ size"?

Tags: articles

I am thinking how to write articles here:

> 1. The result is the map of the size *x* × *y* which is not a grid.
> 2. The result is the map of a size *x* × *y* which is not a grid.
> 3. The result is the map of the size *x* × *y* which is not a grid.

I think *the* in "the map" because it is specifying size. Probably, *a* in "a map" when it is mentioned for the first time.

But there is the specific size *x* × *y* which makes me uncertain about the case.

How can you say use the articles in such a case?

Comment: Is there a reason (homework?) why you _must_ use an article? Because "a map of size _x_ × _y_" is the most natural form.

Answer (score 2):

If I were creating such a map I would say 'the result is an 8.5" x 11" map, without a grid'. Of course use your own measurements.

Comment: I cannot put values there. I must use "x \times y". So probably "the result is  an x \times y map" is ok. What do you think?

Comment: If I couldn't use measurements I would say "the result is a map X(units) by Y(units), without a grid". I would type out "by" so as not to confuse the X axis with the "x" of multiplication. Otherwise you end up with "XxY" which just seems awkward, and detrimental to clear understanding, to me at least.